# Coded UI: How to automate the windows that are closing when crosshair tool is placed on them?

Tags: coded-ui-tests, windows-10-universal

I am using Coded UI Test Project(Universal Windows)for automating Universal Windows apps.During automation of Universal Windows apps,I made assertions through crosshair tool and tried below scenario:
Launched calculator app--> From more options,I selected "Date calculation"option--> Clicked on "From" or "To" calendar--> Related calendar window opens--> Tried to make assertions through crosshair tool for selecting From and To dates for calculation of dates.At this point on wards when crosshair tool is placed on opened calendar windows,calendar window is closing and I am unable to make assertions and automate.

Answer (score 0):

It can be captured using WindowsLogo  + I (Visual studio 2010), but it would not work if you are using Windows 10 os. [Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ee33351-ab9f-41d7-9bdf-6b2f7186b21a/coded-ui-how-to-select-element-from-list-which-get-closed-when-we-click-crosshair-tool-on-test?forum=visualstudiogeneral#6ee33351-ab9f-41d7-9bdf-6b2f7186b21a)

For, Visual studio 2013,2015 Ctrl + I can be used.